# Choosing right PK from not simple composite key in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I build a database of a local store.
I have these entities:

> Product(product_id(PK),product_name,..),
>   Customer(customer_id(PK),customer_name,..)   Order or
>   ProductBasket(order_id(PK),product_id(PK,FK),product_quantity)
>   CustomerOrders(customerOrders_id,customer_id(FK),order_id(FK))

How to set PK in rigth way in Hibernate, bcs there is composite key of atributes, one of which is not in simple type(Product product)?

Should I create another entity specially for order_id where it will be PK and add surogate key to the Order entity?

Comment: What kind of key do you need ? I.e. String, BigInteger etc ?

Comment: BTW Check [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16439_01/doc.1013/e13981/cmp30cfg001.htm)

Comment: I guess i think in right direction, i will make another entity for order_id to make orders many-to-many table with surrogate key.
Problem is what if i do not need one more entity? What should i do?
I need simple integer primary key

Comment: Ok, so you are simply looking for many to many. Check this then https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ManyToMany You need no any special composite keys, or entities for the reference tables. @JoinTable exist instead

Comment: 2. In any case no to reinvent the wheal, if you are building the web store using Java it mind be a better solution to use an existing e-Commerce framework for example an open souce [broadleafcommerce](http://www.broadleafcommerce.com). It have database an many another e-Commerce aspects alrady designed.

Comment: No, it is test task, i try to work with JPA